# Validation in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I am using GWT and want to so validation of email using the java code i.e. using the regular expressions,but when I am using the code:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package org.ArosysLogin.client;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class EmailValidator{

      private Pattern pattern;
      private Matcher matcher;

      private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN =
                   "^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

      public EmailValidator(){
          pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
      }

      /**
       * Validate hex with regular expression
       * @param hex hex for validation
       * @return true valid hex, false invalid hex
       */
      public boolean validate(final String hex){

          matcher = pattern.matcher(hex);
          return matcher.matches();


      }
}
```

.It is giving me run time error in the build.xml.Can you please tell me why this is occurring and what is its solution.

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace you are getting on console?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Java regex is not available in GWT. You should use [GWT's RegExp](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/regexp/shared/RegExp.html).

Answer (score 6):

This is code is for validating email id. I have checked it. It's working fine in GWT.

```
String  s ="survi@gmail.com";
Boolean b = s.matches(
 "^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$");
System.out.println("email is " + b);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, it should not work. But I accidentially found that you can also use java.lang.String's matches method.

So, you could do this:

```
public boolean validate(final String hex){
  return ((hex==null) || hex.matches(EMAIL_PATTERN));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
if(email.matches("^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$")){
    GWT.log("Email Address Valid");
}else{
 GWT.log("Email Address Invalid");
 valid = false;
}
```